# Chaning the image url with a regular expression

Tags: regex, url, url-rewriting

I have to change a url that looks like

```
http://my-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2011/10/PiaggioBeverly-001-106x106.jpg
```

into this format

```
http://my-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2011/10/106x106/PiaggioBeverly-001.jpg
```

I understand I need to create a regular expression pattern that will divide the initial url into three groups:

1. http://my-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/
2. 2011/10/
3. PiaggioBeverly-001-106x106.jpg

and then cut off the resolution string (106x106) from the third group, get rid of the hyphen at the end and move the resolution next to the second. Any idea how to get it done using something like `preg_replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search this : `(.*\/)(\w+-\d+)-(.*?)\.`

and replace with : `\1\3/\2.`

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/fX7gC2

Answer (score 1):

The pattern will be as follow(for input `uploads/2011/10/PiaggioBeverly-001-106x106.jpg`)

```
^(.*/)(.+?)(\d+x\d+)(\.jpg)$
```

And the groups will be holding as follows:

```
$1 = uploads/2011/10/
$2 = PiaggioBeverly-001-
$3 = 106x106
$4 = .jpg
```

Now rearrange as per your need. You can check this example [from online](http://regex101.com/r/cQ9zP1).

As you have mentioned about `preg_replace()`, so if its in PHP, you can use [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/preg_match) for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$oldurl = "http://my-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2011/10/PiaggioBeverly-001-106x106.jpg";

$newurl = preg_replace('%(.*?)/(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)\.(\w+)%sim', '$1/$4/$2-$3.jpg', $oldurl);



echo $newurl;
#http://my-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2011/10/106x106/PiaggioBeverly-001.jpg
?>
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/ZekyBw)

**EXPLANATION:**

```
Options: dot matches newline; case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “/” literally «/»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\w+)»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “-” literally «-»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(\w+)»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “-” literally «-»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 4 «(\w+)»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 5 «(\w+)»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```